# Saving and Loading a Multindexed Pandas Dataframe and retaining the Column Structure

Tags: python, pandas, csv, multi-index

I can not find a way to save properly and retrieve properly a multi-indexed pandas dataframe, so that to retain the multi-indexed column structure. For a reproducible example:

[image]

```
toy_data.to_json()
'{"["GOOG","Shares"]":{"1521849600000":null,"1521936000000":null,"1522368000000":null,"1522454400000":694548763.0,"1522540800000":null},"["GOOG","ROE"]":{"1521849600000":null,"1521936000000":null,"1522368000000":null,"1522454400000":0.1076,"1522540800000":null},"["FB","Shares"]":{"1521849600000":null,"1521936000000":null,"1522368000000":null,"1522454400000":2398606201.0,"1522540800000":null},"["FB","ROE"]":{"1521849600000":null,"1521936000000":null,"1522368000000":null,"1522454400000":0.2465,"1522540800000":null}}'

toy_data.to_csv('toy_data.csv')

toy_data1 = pd.read_csv('toy_data.csv')
```

[image]

Comment: have you tried using the index_col parameter of the read_csv ? (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't provided usable sample data, but I'm fairly certain that all you need to do is pass `header=[0, 1]`, and `index_col=0` as arguments to `read_csv`.

Answer (score 2):

#### `read_csv`

Using the `header` and `index_col` arguments in `read_csv` will get you what you need.

```
toy_data.to_csv('sample.csv')
pd.read_csv('sample.csv', header=[0, 1], index_col=[0])

Company       GOOG          FB     
Indicators  Shares  ROE Shares  ROE
Quarter_end                        
2018-03-24     NaN  NaN    NaN  NaN
2018-03-25     NaN  NaN    NaN  NaN
2018-03-30     NaN  NaN    NaN  NaN
2018-03-31     1.0  2.0    3.0  4.0
2018-04-01     NaN  NaN    NaN  NaN
```

---

#### `read_hdf`

Saving to `hdf` might be a better option.

```
toy_data.to_hdf('sample.h5', 'toy_key')
pd.read_hdf('sample.h5', 'toy_key')

Company       GOOG          FB     
Indicators  Shares  ROE Shares  ROE
Quarter_end                        
2018-03-24     NaN  NaN    NaN  NaN
2018-03-25     NaN  NaN    NaN  NaN
2018-03-30     NaN  NaN    NaN  NaN
2018-03-31     1.0  2.0    3.0  4.0
2018-04-01     NaN  NaN    NaN  NaN
```

---

#### Setup

```
cols = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(
    [['GOOG', 'FB'], ['Shares', 'ROE']],
    names=['Company', 'Indicators']
)
idx = pd.to_datetime(
    ['2018-03-24', '2018-03-25', '2018-03-30',
     '2018-03-31', '2018-04-01']
).rename('Quarter_end')

toy_data = pd.DataFrame([
    [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
    [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
    [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
    [1, 2, 3, 4],
    [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
], idx, cols)
```

Comment: Good answer. Nice to know that `hdf` natively supports multiindices on read/write in `pandas`.